# Python - Mysqldb install Error [ ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:]

Tags: python, mysql, database, visual-studio, mysql-python

I was able to install Mysqldb with the pip install mysql-python command before(in Pycharm), but after installing Visual Code yesterday, it now gives an error. I did everything. I installed Visual Studio Build Tools, deleted and installed Python and Anaconda, but it still won't install. What should I do?

```
pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
  Building wheel for mysql-python (setup.py) ... \  WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1254
error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\90539\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tn8inoxo\\mysql-python
\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\90539\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tn8inoxo\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\90539\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-dk9sq9jv'
       cwd: C:\Users\90539\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tn8inoxo\mysql-python\
  Complete output (33 lines):
  C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:669: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the u
nderscore name 'distribution_name' instead
    warnings.warn(
  C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:669: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the unde
rscore name 'build_requires' instead
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -
D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\in
clude\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
    Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... /    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1254
error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\90539\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tn8inoxo\\mysql-pyth
on\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\90539\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tn8inoxo\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.re
ad().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\90539\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ac858le3\install-reco
rd.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\Include\mysql-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\90539\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tn8inoxo\mysql-python\
    Complete output (33 lines):
    C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:669: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the
 underscore name 'distribution_name' instead
      warnings.warn(
    C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:669: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the un
derscore name 'build_requires' instead
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1)
 -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Mi
crosoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program File
s (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\90539\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
\pip-install-tn8inoxo\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\90539\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tn8inoxo\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'ope
n'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\90539\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-record-ac858le3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\90539\Anaconda3\Include\mysql-python' Check the logs for full command
 output.
```

Comment: Why only provide pictures which contain text (and not simply copy paste the text directly into your question ?

Comment: Why do you provide only the error messages, and not the action that you where performing?

Comment: Sorry @Luuk, I update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your python version changed from 2.7 to some 3.x version? See the package documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/), it reads:

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently
> supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is
> supported.

If you are now on 3.x try `pip install mysqlclient`.